# How do we enhance the SE spell check dictionary?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, formatting

Ever notice how some common Blender words that we use on a regular basis, e.g. *viewport*, *SHFT*, *CTRL*, and *wireframe*, always throw a spelling exception? Is there any way to get these, and other common Blender terms added to the Blender.stackexchange spell check dictionary? And if there is a way to do this, what other words should be added?

Comment: Spellchecking is handled by the browser, the site has no control over this. (Even the browser likely uses external libraries and dictionaries from other packages)

Answer (score 4):

As gandalf3 said in the comments, the site has no control over the spell checking, that is handled completely by the browsers.

However you can add the trouble words to your own browser's dictionary.

You can just right-click the word and select *Add to dictionary.*
Instructions for [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95604?hl=en) and [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-use-firefox-spell-checker#w_correcting-misspelled-words), (if you need instructions for a different browser try [this link](http://firefox.com))

Words such as: *shader*, *compositing*, *outliner* and *viewport* are already in my browsers dictionary.